# Register for Push Notifications Per Target

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app with several Targets. Does anyone know how I can best setup a way to register for Push Notifications on a per-target basis? For example, if I implement `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, for the Targets that don't have Push Notifications enabled (no entitlement/incorrect provisioning profile config), Apple's code validator will notice that I'm registering for push notifications and give me a warning indicating the app might have been signed incorrectly.

Is there a way to register for Push Notifications for specific Targets?

Comment: It's generally Bad Form to make the code know anything about the development environment it's running in, unless it's a simple `DEBUG` flag.

Comment: Add `SOME_FLAG=1` to `Preprocessor Macros` under build settings. Make sure the flag is unique to the configuration. Then just `#ifdef SOME_FLAG` in the code and do whatever you want.